# How can one uninstall virtualenvwrapper?

Tags: python, macos, uninstallation, virtualenvwrapper

I believe that I have installed virtualenvwrapper incorrectly (the perils of following different tutorials for python setup).

I would like to remove the extension completely from my Mac OSX system but there seems to be no documentation on how to do this.

Does anyone know how to completely reverse the installation? Its wreaking havoc with my attempts to compile python scripts.

Comment: It's hard to say without more information about what tutorials or methods you used to install it. Can you add some example output that shows what "wreaking havoc" means?

Comment: Hi Roshi thank you for your reply, I followed the following tutorial to setup python:

https://hackercodex.com/guide/python-development-environment-on-mac-osx/ 

and for virtualenvwrapper:

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-virtual-environments-in-python--cms-28272

If you look under the comment by NickUK on the HackerCodex tutorial, you can see a screen dump of the problem.

Comment: With my noob understanding, I think when I create virtual environments, they are created in a folder called virtualenvs while activation seems to activate in a hidden macOS folder named .virtualenvs. Presumably because the virtualenvwrapper installation requires the command:

'export WORKON_HOME=.virtualenvs'

Comment: I have tried setting work_home to virtualenvs but this seems to do nothing. On suggestion by a coding colleague to work around all of this I installed Anaconda which I imagine has changed more settings.

In short... Ive made a huge mess and really need a hand. Any help you can give would be hugely appreciated

Comment: If you used `pip` to install things, you can get rid of them by using `pip uninstall foo` where foo is the python package you want to uninstall.

Comment: Hi there, I did use pip to install. I have tried using pip uninstall but it returns

'Cannot uninstall requirement virtualenvwrapper, not installed'

this despite the fact that it is clearly installed within the user profile

Comment: So part of the problem here is the fact that there are several different "pip"s on your machine now. There's the OSX system pip, the brew installed pip and then a pip in each virtualenv you created. So now you have to look through and figure out which `pip` actually did the install and remove it there.

Comment: Jens, if I recall correctly, there was no option for a comment on the question itself. I hadn't read this (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) yet, so I did the wrong thing and put my comment in an answer. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 12):

```
pip uninstall virtualenvwrapper
```

Or

```
sudo pip uninstall virtualenvwrapper
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

On windows - This works great
pip uninstall virtualenvwrapper-win

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).